# Do not show children of a category

Tags: posts, wp-query, query

I'm trying the next code:

```
$categoria = get_the_category();
$hijosCategoria = (array) get_term_children($categoria[0]->term_id, 'category');
$queryBase = array("cat"=>$categoria[0]->term_id,"category__not_in"=>$hijosCategoria);
$objetoBase = new WP_Query($queryBase);
if ($objetoBase->have_posts()){
    while($objetoBase->have_posts()){
        $objetoBase->the_post();
        ?>
        <section class="contenido">
            <h2 class="titulo-contenido"><?php the_title();?></h2>
            <article class="texto-contenido">
                <?php the_content();?>
            </article>    
        </section>
        <?php        
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

But I can always see the children of the post. I do not understand why because "$hijosCategoria" have the correct value.

It's like "$queryBase" isn't working with category__not_in.

Do I need something more in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the parameter [`category__in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) - if you do this, then there is no need for `cat` and `category__not_in`. `category__in` does give you back results from the categor(y/ies) specified, but does *not* include results for the children of the specified categor(y/ies).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$categoria = get_the_category();
$objetoBase = new WP_Query('category__in='.$categoria[0]->term_id);
```

In the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) you can find the example of category__in which will not show the children.

Hope that works,
Diogo

Comment: Kind of what I said ;) +1 for the code example